# A more acceptable word to replace the word "rectum"?

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language, minced-oaths, euphemisms

I wrote in a short paragraph describing how a cartoon character, after being eaten up by a shark, swam through the shark's internal body and fled from its rectum. It was meant to be a cartoon/game-like kind of idea.

A friend read and thought it was not very nice of me to have written it in this manner. I suspect it could be the word "*rectum*" that has made him feel uneasy.

Seriously, is it really crude of me to have written it that way?

What could be a better phrasing or word to replace "*rectum*" so that the meaning remains and does not sound too offensive?

Comment: Chocolate starfish.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA That was not very nice of you. I am going not to eat starfishes for the rest of my days. `;)`

Comment: Lavender passage?

Comment: For a cartoon description, I'd use something like *hind end* or *backside*.

Comment: *Sphicter*?  Seems pretty benign.

Comment: How about this: The cartoon character, after being swallowed by a shark, swam through the shark's GI tract and was then evacuated. (*Evacuation* is used in medicine for "an emptying," specifically emptying of the bowels. And it's kind of a funny word.)

Comment: I can see it now... The last level, there hangs the sign saying "Evacuate!".  Or maybe make it a button the character has to press?

Comment: How about '...and passed through the shark'.

Comment: A walk-on quaterback went to football team tryouts. Coach tosses a football to him and says "How well can you pass that ball?" The young kid said "Coach, I don't think I could even swallow it."

Comment: Rectum? Damn near killed 'em.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that the standard for consumed cartoon characters is to be regurgitated rather than evacuated.  I don't believe I've ever seen a cartoon where the swallowed character made it all the way through the alimentary tract; they always exit via the mouth.

Comment: The problem is not with the word (though it does sound a bit to medical). The problem is the level of detail. We usually avoid saying exactly how the solid waste leaves the body. Replace the reference to the actual opening with something more general such as "the rear".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word

> rectum

like the nearby anus, is somewhat more formal than the alternatives, which are pretty informal or vulgar.

It is the concept itself, traveling through the alimentary canal and exiting from the waste area that probably invoked the reaction of your friend.

The word itself, 'rectum' is fine (like 'penis', 'vagina', etc), it's the situation that may be objectionable.

To clarify, there are words (expressions) and there are concepts (mental ideas) and words can be used to talk about concepts. Both can be distasteful or pleasant or somewhere in between. But they don't necessarily match.

A euphemism is a pleasant word for an unpleasant subject (these are fairly common, like the clinical anatomical words for potty talk). There are also dysphemisms which are rude words for more pleasant concepts (derogatory terms for ethnicities fall here).

It seems strange that there is such a disconnect, and often enough a euphemism will eventually become more and more a taboo expression, colored by the taboo concept (witness 'commode' or 'toilet').

Of course, anything related to poop is going to elicit a special reaction in the 10 year old in all of us, however euphemized the words might be.

---

To answer what you want directly, basically to 'spin' the wording so it all sounds ..um... palatable, instead of a euphemistic synonym, you'll probably want to say something slightly oblique like:

> ...and came out the other end.

Comment: +1.  I'd just add that if you're looking for something more euphemistic you could try "back passage" but to be honest it's hard to write such a juvenile idea in an adult fashion.

Comment: 'rectum', 'anus', 'cloaca' are pretty clinical to me; 'poop chute' is informal and jocular, somewhat vulgar but not terribly; 'asshole', and 'shit hole' are pretty vulgar.